# How can I add a Polymer 3 element to my Polymer 1 application

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

My application is built with Polymer 1, and I couldn't upgrade it to the Polymer 3 with the upgrade tool by polymer team.
So I want to build new developments & elements now using the new Polymer 3 component & syntax, is there a way to have such a hybrid application between Polymer 1 & 3?
If yes I want to see now how to process to add polymer 3 core to it.
Else, is it possible to add `Polymer 2` elements and core as the 3rd version won't work.
now I'm using bower and in `bower.json` I've:

```
"dependencies": {
    "polymer": "polymer/polymer#=1.7.0"
},
"resolutions": {
    "polymer": "=1.7.0",
}
```

Comment: Your base platform should be `Polymer 3`, but you can run all polymer 1 element in with some very basic syntax changes. So, first init your main directory with Polymer 3. /Briefly: All-polymer components are compatible with downward but not upward. So I would try to explain more if you want to go forward soo

Comment: thanks but I'm thinking about upgrading all the project if there is no possibility to use polymer3 components

Comment: you could see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977992/combining-polymer-1-0-with-3-0