# Combining polymer 1.0 with 3.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-3.x

I am working on modifying an existing project which is built in polymer 1.0.

As the current version of polymer is polymer 3.0 how can we include the same without making much changes with the existing application.

The main difference than i found out is that in polymer 1.0 `.html` files are imported whereas in polymer 3.0 `.js` files are imported.

Added below the comparison between two imports

## polymer 1

```
<head>
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
</head>
```

## polymer 3

```
import {PolymerElement, html} from '@polymer/polymer';
```

When we try to install components js files are being created. Is there any method to create old type polymer components via CLI?

Comment: did you try `modulizer`?  https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-modulizer

Comment: @HakanC modulizer deals with 2.0 to 3.0. did not find any doc supporting conversion of 1.0 -> 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should try to create **Polymer 3** elements in **HTML** files, as HTML imports are either **not supported** (in FF, for example), or **about to become obsolete** (in Chrome, for example), as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports).

A mix between components crated with Polymer 1.x/2.x (with HTML imports) and **Polymer 3.x** and/or **LitElement** would be to have an **webpack** build step, that would bundle all the JS files. (for example have a single JS file where you import your new elements, pass it throgh webpack and include it in your Polymer 1.x app).

But in the long run migrating *away* from HTML imports seems like the safer bet. You might want to take a look at the modulizer, as @HakanC suggested.

Comment: I guess (did not test) a **hack** could be to create your Polymer 3 elements in JS, and just have some wrapper HTML files, in which you include those elements with script tags, just so you would have an HTML to import.. but, aside from the fact that I never did this, I am not even saying that it would be a good idea, still think you should migrate to JS files..

Comment: as said in description i am provided with an existing application which is built using polymer 1.0. 

When we try to build/import a new component it will be in the form of polymer 3.0.

As mentioned by @HakanC modulizer converts 2.0 to 3.0

Comment: @SanjeevS right, and for that you can use webpack to bundle your Polymer 3 components. You could have an entry point that imports your components, and that one could be built by webpack into a single file. I was suggesting migrating and maybe using the modulizer only as a later solution, as it's more future-proof.

Comment: I didn't get u on "bundle your components". Can both types of polymer exist simultaneously in a single web app???

Comment: @SanjeevS as long as you don't define the same element twice (which can also happen by including 3rd party elements, like `paper-input`, for example, in both the HTML and the JS format) it doesn't matter in which kind of file you define them.. what matters is that line where you register the definition `window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);`.. so yes, you could have some elements defined in Polymer 3.x JS files and include them in your Polymer 1.x app